# SQL and GridView

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I am currently doing a project on web service for wine. I have the wine table with wineName and wineType. Also I have the search function implemented in the webservice coding as well as a separate webform to call the function of the search function

I have the following code for performing search in the search service:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function Search(ByVal searchName As String) As System.Data.DataSet
    Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim con As New SqlConnection(connectionString)

    Dim selectSql As String = "SELECT * From Wine WHERE WineType='" & searchName + "'"

    Dim selectAdapter As New Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(selectSql, con)
    Dim ds As New Data.DataSet
    con.Open()
    selectAdapter.Fill(ds, "Wine")
    con.Close()

    Return ds

End Function
```

As for the webform, it's just a simple page with textbox labeled as searchName, a button and a gridView1 tied to ObjectDataSource.

This is the coding i have for webform:

```
Partial Class Search
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim searching As searchwine.Service = New searchwine.Service

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If searchName.Text = "" Then
            lblDisplayError.Text = "Can't search empty field!"

        Else

            Dim ds As DataSet = searching.Search(searchName.Text)
            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
            GridView1.DataBind()
            GridView1.Visible = True
            lblDisplayError.Visible = False

        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        lblDisplayError.Text = ""
        GridView1.Visible = False
    End Sub

End Class
```

Everything seems fine, but i have the following error when i want to do a search:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at Service.Search(String searchName)

Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: Ahh, this is painful to read! Please format it.

Comment: Took care of it... much more readable now.

Comment: which line does it throw the error?

Comment: it occurs at Dim ds As DataSet = searching.Search(searchName.Text)

Comment: @user1283875 we meant within the Search function. The error is thrown somewhere inside that function, be I don't see exactly where.

Comment: can you first test your web service to whether it is working or not, then add a breakpoint on   GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0) line to see whether the ds is not null or not

Answer (score 1):

I've looked through your code a couple times and I can't see what's causing the NullReferenceException. My best guess is that it couldn't find a connection string name "ConnectionString" in your web.config file, but even that doesn't quite seem to fit.

I can suggest some improvements to your search code. Hopefully you'll at least get a better error message out of this:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function Search(ByVal searchName As String) As System.Data.DataSet
    Dim ds As New Data.DataSet()
    Dim connectionString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString

    Using con As New SqlConnection(connectionString), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * From Wine WHERE WineType= @SearchName", con)

        'I had to guess at the exact length and type of the field here
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@SearchName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = searchName 

        Dim selectAdapter As New Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd, con)
        selectAdapter.Fill(ds, "Wine")
    End Using

    Return ds
End Function
```

But in the end I expect you'll need to step through the method and see exactly which line above throws the exception.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are missing a `New`

```
Dim ds As DataSet = searching.Search(searchName.Text)
```

Should be...

```
Dim ds As **New** DataSet = searching.Search(searchName.Text)
```

Comment: but when i add in the NEW, there are two errors. namely: 
"End of Statement expected" and 
"Name ds is not declared"

Comment: This is just wrong. All it would do is create an empty dataset that you'd immediately throw away.